# For what values of "a" does the resulting system have (a) no solution, (b) a unique solution, (c) infinitely many solutions?

Tags: linear-algebra

```
x + y + z = 2
2x + 3y + 2z = 5
2x + 3y + (a^2 - 1)z = a + 1
```

I got to the reduced echelon form, the matrix looks like this:

```
1 0     1   -2
0 1     0    4 
0 0 (a^2-3) a-4
```

It seems to me that both x, y and z are basic variables. Is this true? 
If there indeed is a unique solution, can you find what it is? 
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

From your third row it is evident that if $a^2=3$ there is no solution,otherwise there is a unique solution.

Answer (score 1):

Use Cramer's rule.

First, the determinant of the coefficient matrix $\begin{pmatrix}1&1&1 \\ 2&3&2 \\ 2&3&{a^2-1}\end{pmatrix}$ is $(3a^2-3-6)-(2a^2-2-4)+(6-6)=3a^2-9-2a^2+6=a^2-3$. This is zero if $a=\pm \sqrt{3}$.

Then, replacing each column with the column of constants gives the following determinants.

- First column (for x):

$\begin{align}
\operatorname{det} \begin{pmatrix}2&1&1 \\ 5&3&2 \\ {a+1}&3&{a^2-1}\end{pmatrix}&=2(3a^2-3-6)-(5a^2-5-2a-2)+(15-3a-3)\\
&=2(3a^2-9)-(5a^2-2a-7)+(12-3a)\\
&=6a^2-18-5a^2+2a+7+12-3a\\
&=a^2-a+1
\end{align}$

- Second column (for y):

$\begin{align}
\operatorname{det} \begin{pmatrix}1&2&1 \\ 2&5&2 \\ 2&{a+1}&{a^2-1}\end{pmatrix}&=(5a^2-5-2a-2)-2(2a^2-2-4)+(2a+2-10)\\
&=(5a^2-2a-7)-2(2a^2-6)+(2a-8)\\
&=5a^2-2a-7-4a^2+12+2a-8\\
&=a^2-3
\end{align}$

- Third column (for z):

$\begin{align}
\operatorname{det} \begin{pmatrix}1&1&2 \\ 2&3&5 \\ 2&3&{a+1}\end{pmatrix}&=(3a+3-15)-(2a+2-10)+2(6-6)\\
&=(3a-12)-(2a-8)+2(0)\\
&=3a-12-2a+8+0\\
&=a-4
\end{align}$

Finally, by Cramer's rule, if $a \neq \pm \sqrt{3}$, then the solution will be the following: $x=\frac{a^2-a+1}{a^2-3}, y=1, z=\frac{a-4}{a^2-3}$.

Answer (score 0):

Multiplying the first equation by $-2$ and adding to the second we get
$$y=1$$ doing the same with the first and last equation we get
$$y-2z+(a^2-1)z=a-3$$ Since $y=1$ we get
$$z(a^2-1-2)=a-4$$